# Oracle Data Access FileNotFound: Oracle.DataAccess.Common.Configuration.Section.xsd

Tags: c#, oracle, nuget

Yesterday May 11, 2016, my C# code on .NET 4.6 was happily reading data from Oracle using the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess drivers version 12.1.24160419 from nuget.  Today the damned thing is throwing a FileNotFound error looking for this file: Oracle.DataAccess.Common.Configuration.Section.xsd

None of my various machines have that file.  Never heard of this thing.  Any idea why all of a sudden my code is looking for this file?

Comment: I copied a random xsd and get it that name, which made it work.  But then I got an exception on program exit talking about System.ObjectDisposedException.  This is strange....

Comment: Did you figure out what the cause was?  I'm using an older version of ODP.NET (12.1.022) and have been dealing with exactly the same bug today.  Oddly enough, everything was also working fine until yesterday. Strange indeed.

Comment: I have not figured it out yet. The fake XSD work around is lame but effective. Eventually we will solve it though and I will update this post!

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  It seems that the problem is specific to x64.  When building as "Any CPU", the error is not thrown.  The other thing I found is that that it doesn't seem to actually break anything, and the reason I was seeing the error was because the application was running with the debugger attached and set to break on all errors. From the command line, everything works as expected with reading and writing data. I'll try creating the fake XSD though as a temporary workaround to stop the exception being thrown altogether.

Comment: One more facing the same bug, starting from today... what's interesting is that this error is happening in one machine, out of other stations where the same TFS code is working fine, without throwing this xsd exception.

Comment: @Mun: your remark about the build settings did not work for me (mine is already `Any CPU`).

Comment: The interesting part is that the other stations where the code is working as it used to - do not have this .xsd file in the location specified by the exception.

Answer (score 3):

I stepped over this exception while debugging and it connected to my db correctly. I assume this is an internal exception handling an optional configuration method.

It went away after unselecting `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` in the "Exceptions..." dialogue, so I believe it is safe to ignore, it should not bubble up to your exception handler.